# Reg-Key for PageSetup on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, page-setup

I want to change the Pagesetup on IE11 with a Regkey entry via GPO.

On a previous version from IE I have added the key via GPO to:

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup"

When I set the Regkey for IE11 on the same Registryfolder this has no effect.

In which Reg folder does IE11 save the PageSetup?